# background color not being applied to button in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying have random color generator which generates a random color and then pass it onto a prop of card
Even though the css is being applied but i still cannot see the effect of the color.

```js
import { useClipboard } from "@mantine/hooks";
import { IoMdShareAlt } from "react-icons/io";
import { MdDone } from "react-icons/md";
import "./page.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface CardProps {
    icon: string;
    title: string;
    subtitle: string;
}

const Card = ({ icon, title, subtitle }: CardProps) => {
    const clipboard = useClipboard({ timeout: 1000 });
    const [color, setColor] = useState("");
    const colors = [
        "Slate",
        "Gray",
        "Zinc",...
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        setColor(
            `bg-${colors[title.length % colors.length].toLocaleLowerCase()}-500`,
        );
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="relative m-6 flex w-[300px] flex-col font-[--font-roboto] font-bold shadow">
            <div className="h-[70%]">
                <img src={icon} className="h-full w-full" alt={title} />
            </div>
            <div className="relative">
                <button
                    onClick={() => clipboard.copy("Hello, world!")}
                    className={`absolute right-5 grid aspect-square h-10 translate-y-[-50%] place-items-center rounded-full ${color}`}
                >
                    {clipboard.copied ? (
                        <MdDone size={25} color="white" />
                    ) : (
                        <IoMdShareAlt size={25} color="white" />
                    )}
                </button>
                <div className="p-6">
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    <h4 className="font-light">{subtitle}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

[image]

i tried passing it down as a prop from the parent component but it still gives me the same result

Answer (score 1):

The `colors` appear to be static values, and presumably the titles are not changing often, I don't see any point in storing a color in state since it is a trivial to compute the string. Compute the color value so it's available on the initial render. See if this resolves any rendering issues working with Tailwind.

Example:

```
const colors = [
  "Slate",
  "Gray",
  "Zinc",...
].map(c => c.toLocaleLowerCase());

const Card = ({ icon, title, subtitle }: CardProps) => {
  const clipboard = useClipboard({ timeout: 1000 });
  const color = `bg-${colors[title.length % colors.length]}-500`;

  return (
    <div className="relative m-6 flex w-[300px] flex-col font-[--font-roboto] font-bold shadow">
      <div className="h-[70%]">
        <img src={icon} className="h-full w-full" alt={title} />
      </div>
      <div className="relative">
        <button
          onClick={() => clipboard.copy("Hello, world!")}
          className={`absolute right-5 grid aspect-square h-10 translate-y-[-50%] place-items-center rounded-full ${color}`}
        >
          {clipboard.copied ? (
            <MdDone size={25} color="white" />
          ) : (
            <IoMdShareAlt size={25} color="white" />
          )}
        </button>
        <div className="p-6">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
          <h4 className="font-light">{subtitle}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply the tailwind style, you must import its classes completely.
so you can consider two solutions for using dynamic classes:

1)Use the full name of the tailwind classes in the desired conditions:

```
const colors = [
        "bg-slate-500",
        "bg-gray-500",
        "bg-zinc-500",...
    ];

const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
.
.
.
<button className={`${randomColor()} p-2`}>...</button>
```

2)you can use css variables:

```
    const colors = [
            "#be3455",
            "#f69a92",
            "#621a55",
        ];

    const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    .
    .
    .
    <button
       className='bg-[var(--customPadding)] p-2'
       style={{ '--customPadding':randomColor}}/><button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not split the tailwind class names in your code, because the parser cant find it anymore. I would do something like that:

```
  <button
    onClick={() => clipboard.copy("Hello, world!")}
    className={`absolute right-5 grid aspect-square h-10 translate-y-[-50%] place-items-center rounded-full ${
      color === "Slate"
        ? "bg-slate-500"
        : color === "Gray"
        ? "bg-gray-500"
        : color === "Zink"
        ? "bg-zink-500"
        : ""
    }`}
  >
    {clipboard.copied ? (
      <MdDone size={25} color="white" />
    ) : (
      <IoMdShareAlt size={25} color="white" />
    )}
  </button>
```

This is a bit tricky but saves you some code and makes it more readable.